# Android query cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

i have a problem with a cursor. i created a alarm manager that pick a value  to compare with another in looping.

My problem is this: if the cursor is outside of the loop this pick only my `first` value (if exsist only one value pick only this obviously).... if the cursor is in the loop, this pick only `last` value (if exsist only one value pick only this obviously).

how to fix this?

my query:

```
public Cursor getRegistry2()
    {
        return (getReadableDatabase().query(
            TabRegistry.TABLE_NAME, 
            TabRegistry.COLUMNS, 
            TabRegistry._ID, 
            null,
            null, 
            null, 
            null));
```

my cursor in service:

```
 Cursor c5 = databaseHelper.getRegistry2();
                     c5.moveToFirst();
                        while(c5.isAfterLast() == false){   
                            tipe = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.TYPE)); 

                            status = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.STATUS)); 
                            number = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.NUMBER)); 
                        c5.moveToNext();
                        }
                       c5.close();
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you'll need to make a bit more clear what you'd _like_ to be the result of this.

Comment: I see nowhere that you are comparing anything.  All you are doing is iterating through the cursor and re-setting the tipe, status and number strings on each pass through, so of course you always get the last values in the cursor.

Comment: the comparison is done by an if cycle in looping... i need compare all value of my  table with this value in the cyle.. the problem is that: he compares only the first and last

Comment: Where are you comparing in your code...?

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers ... Forgive me if  explained badly ..but I was confused about the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, if you are actually trying to find a particular item you need to actually look for it.

Assuming you are looking to compare the status, you might do this:

```
while(c5.isAfterLast() == false){   
    tipe = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.TYPE)); 
    status = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.STATUS)); 
    number = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.NUMBER)); 
    if (status.equals(comparisonString)){
        break;
    }
    c5.moveToNext();
}
```

This would break out of your loop, leaving your values set for the item you were looking for.

Personally, that's a lot of computing overhead and I'd just make the query to look for the comparison value directly and then check and see if the returned cursor was empty.  Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem but something that is strange for me is : `while(c5.isAfterLast() == false){`

Have you tried to replace by `while (c5.moveToNext()) {` and removing `c5.moveToFirst();` ?

Answer (score 0):

**You should know** that you are overwriting the values of `tipe`, `status` and `number` in case your cursor has values more than one.

```
Cursor c5 = databaseHelper.getRegistry2();
if(c5.moveToFirst()){
 do{   
    tipe = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.TYPE)); 

    status = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.STATUS)); 
    number = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.NUMBER));
 }while(c5.moveToNext());
}
c5.close();
```

Comment: And how is this any different?  It's still overwriting the string value each time...

Comment: not much difference, but as i said first, it will overwrite the values since its in a loop.